Automapper - IMongoQueryable ProjectTo ignoring AllowNullDestinationValues
I am mapping source object
public class PlannedCare
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public PlannedCareBatch? BatchStart { get; set; }
}

to
public class PlannedCareDto
{
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public PlannedCareBatchRm? BatchStart { get; set; }
}

Config:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true; //this is default, but just to make sure...
    cfg.CreateMap<PlannedCare, PlannedCareRm>();
    cfg.CreateMap<PlannedCareBatch, PlannedCareBatchRm>();
    // other mappings...
});

All is OK if I use Map method. When I use ProjectTo the destination BatchStart object is always initialized. I want it to remain null if source property BatchStart is null. I am using Mongo DB driver. Where is the problem?
public IQueryable<PlannedCareDto> GetQueryable()
{
    return _collection
        .AsQueryable()
        .ProjectTo<PlannedCareDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
}

I even tried setting NullSubstitue on property, which also does not work. I guess the query will be somehow malformed...
CreateMap<PlannedCare, PlannedCareRm>()
    .ForMember(p => p.BatchStart, d => d.NullSubstitute(null));


Check the execution plan.

I have found the problem.
Automapper expression was OK:
BatchStart = .If ($dtoPlannedCare.BatchStart == .Default(System.Object)) {
            .Default(Care.Domain.QueryServices.PlannedCare.ReadModels.PlannedCareBatchRm)
        } .Else {
            .New Care.Domain.QueryServices.PlannedCare.ReadModels.PlannedCareBatchRm(){
                BatchId = ($dtoPlannedCare.BatchStart).BatchId,
                Status = ($dtoPlannedCare.BatchStart).Status
            }
        },

Mongo exppression:
BatchStart: {
        '$cond': {
          if: { '$eq': ['$BatchStart', null] },
          then: null,
          else: { BatchId: '$BatchStart.BatchId', Status: '$BatchStart.Status' }
        }
      },

Mongo is treating differently non existing properties and null properties. If the property was not present if: { '$eq': ['$BatchStart', null] }, was evaluated to false.
